# For the langauge L={0^i1^i | i>=0} DFA possible or not?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

At many places I have read that the following language is not a regular, and thus it is impossible to express this in terms of  Finite Automata.

> L={0^i1^i | i>=0}

But I tried  this as follows.

[image]

Can somebody explain the fallacy?

Comment: A DFA must decide the language. Hence, not only if $w$ is in $L$, the DFA should recongnize it, but also if the DFA recognizes a word $w$, it should be in $L$.
The DFA you gave verifies $L \subset L_{DFA}$ but your DFA recognizes strings that are not in $L$.

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example of a string that it recognizes , but is not in the language ?

Comment: Well, the language that your DFA decide is $0^*1^+$, hence it recognizes 1, 0000011, 011111,...$\not \in L$

Comment: You cleared a big  misconception I was having. Thanks

Comment: @Timot Why not make this an answer?

Comment: I'm closing this as duplicate because the question has been answered already. The language is a standard example of a *non-regular* language, so NFA can not model it.